# Is the set of failures of the Collatz property a sum-free set?

Tags: number-theory

That is, let M be the set to which x belongs if, and only if, x is a positive integer for which the Collatz property fails. Is M a sum-free set? Of course, if the Collatz conjecture is true, then M is empty and hence, by material implication, a sum-free set.

(Of course, one could ask an analogous questions about other things, such as Goldbach’s conjecture.)

Comment: this doesn't sound like a homework problem ... but what have you tried :)

Comment: Since $x \in M$ implies $2 \cdot x \in M$, not unless it is empty, since $x + x = 2 \cdot x$.